# Making a discord.py chat filter, giving error "await" is invalid syntax

Tags: python, filter, bots, discord, discord.py

I am making a chat filter for my discord bot that will warn people two times before banning them if they say a bad word. I know that there are better ways to do this but please do not cite them as i do not want to re code my whole bot. Here is my chat filter (i have replaced the cuss words with "censored"):

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global warn_count
    if "censored" in message.content:
        channel = await message.author.create_dm()
        warn_count = warn_count + 1
        if warn_count == 2:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, given two warnings, message: {}, banned {}.".format(message.content,message.author)
            await channel.send("That was your second warning. You have been kicked until further notice.")
            await message.author.ban()
        else:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, by {}, message: {}, warned.".format(message.author,message.content))
            await channel.send("WARNNG: please do not {} it is against our rules. If you do this again you will be kicked until further notice. If you believe this is an error please dm e at wolverhulk13#1112")

    if "censored" in message.content:

        channel = await message.author.create_dm()
        warn_count = warn_count + 1
        if warn_count == 2:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, given two warnings, message: {}, banned {}.".format(message.content,message.author)
            await channel.send("That was your second warning. You have been kicked until further notice.")
            await message.author.ban()
        else:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, by {}, message: {}, warned.".format(message.author,message.content))
            await channel.send("WARNNG: please do not swear it is against our rules. If you do this again you will be kicked until further notice. If you believe this is an error please dm me at wolverhulk13#1112")

    if "censored" in message.content:

        channel = await message.author.create_dm()
        warn_count = warn_count + 1
        if warn_count == 2:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, given two warnings, message: {}, banned {}.".format(message.content,message.author))
            await channel.send("That was your second warning. You have been kicked until further notice.")
            await message.author.ban()
        else:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, by {}, message: {}, warned.".format(message.author,message.content))
            await channel.send("WARNNG: please do not swear it is against our rules. If you do this again you will be kicked until further notice. If you believe this is an error please dm me at wolverhulk13#1112")

    if "censored" in message.content:

        channel = await message.author.create_dm()
        warn_count = warn_count + 1
        if warn_count == 2:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, given two warnings, message: {}, banned {}.".format(message.content,message.author))
            channel.send("That was your second warning. You have been kicked until further notice.")
            await message.author.ban()
        else:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, by {}, message: {}, warned.".format(message.author,message.content))
            await channel.send("WARNNG: please do not swear it is against our rules. If you do this again you will be kicked until further notice. If you believe this is an error please dm me at wolverhulk13#1112")

    if "censored" in message.content.split(" "):

        channel = await message.author.create_dm()
        warn_count = warn_count + 1
        if warn_count == 2:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, given two warnings, message: {}, banned {}.".format(message.content,message.author))
            await channel.send("That was your second warning. You have been kicked until further notice.")
            await message.author.ban()
        else:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, by {}, message: {}, warned.".format(message.author,message.content))
            await channel.send("WARNNG: please do not swear it is against our rules. If you do this again you will be kicked until further notice. If you believe this is an error please dm me at wolverhulk13#1112")

    if "censored" in message.content.split(" "):
        warn_count = warn_count + 1
        channel = await message.author.create_dm()
        if warn_count == 2:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, given two warnings, message: {}, banned {}.".format(message.content,message.author))
            await channel.send("That was your second warning. You have been kicked until further notice.")
            await message.author.ban()
        else:
            await channel.send("WARNNG: please do not swear it is against our rules. If you do this again you will be kicked until further notice. If you believe this is an error please dm me at wolverhulk13#1112")
            print("Innapropriate language detected, by {}, message: {}, warned.".format(message.author,message.content))

    if "censored" in message.content:

        channel = await message.author.create_dm()
        warn_count = warn_count + 1
        if warn_count == 2:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, given two warnings, message: {}, banned {}.".format(message.content,message.author))
            await channel.send("That was your second warning. You have been kicked until further notice.")
            await message.author.ban()
        else:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, by {}, message: {}, warned.".format(message.author,message.content))
            await channel.send("WARNNG: please do not swear it is against our rules. If you do this again you will be kicked until further notice. If you believe this is an error please dm me at wolverhulk13#1112")

    if "censored" in message.content:

        channel = await message.author.create_dm()
        warn_count = warn_count + 1
        if warn_count == 2:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, given two warnings, message: {}, banned {}.".format(message.content,message.author))
            await channel.send("That was your second warning. You have been kicked until further notice.")
            await message.author.ban()
        else:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, by {}, message: {}, warned.".format(message.author,message.content))
            await channel.send("WARNNG: please do not swear it is against our rules. If you do this again you will be kicked until further notice. If you believe this is an error please dm me at wolverhulk13#1112")

    if "censored" in message.content:

        channel = await message.author.create_dm()
        warn_count = warn_count + 1
        if warn_count == 2:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, given two warnings, message: {}, banned {}.".format(message.content,message.author))
            await channel.send("That was your second warning. You have been kicked until further notice.")
            await message.author.ban()
        else:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, by {}, message: {}, warned.".format(message.author,message.content))
            await channel.send("WARNNG: please do not swear it is against our rules. If you do this again you will be kicked until further notice. If you believe this is an error please dm me at wolverhulk13#1112")


    if "censored" in message.content:
        channel = await message.author.create_dm()
        warn_count = warn_count + 1
        if warn_count == 2:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, given two warnings, message: {}, banned {}.".format(message.content,message.author))
            await channel.send("That was your second warning. You have been kicked until further notice.")
            await message.author.ban()
        else:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, by {}, message: {}, warned.".format(message.author,message.content))
            await channel.send("WARNNG: please do not swear it is against our rules. If you do this again you will be kicked until further notice. If you believe this is an error please dm me at wolverhulk13#1112")

    else:
        global message_counter
        message_counter = message_counter + 1
        print(message_counter)

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

it returns the error: `File "bot.py", line 25
    await channel.send("That was your second warning. You have bee--- 
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: `. . . banned {}.".format(message.content,message.author)` <- You're missing a closing parenthesis for the `print`. VTC as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to only send a minimal reproducible example. We are only interested in part of the code that is causing the problem, here it's line 25. You don't need to send anything else when talking about a Syntax Error.

About that Syntax Error: When Encountering Syntax Errors, python mentiones the entire line, so just mentioning that it's at `await` in the title sadly does not help either. Good job for sending the entire error message in the post though.

About the Error itself:

The Syntax Error can be found here:

```py
if "censored" in message.content:

        channel = await message.author.create_dm()
        warn_count = warn_count + 1
        if warn_count == 2:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, given two warnings, message: {}, banned {}.".format(message.content,message.author) # close the parenthesis here
            await channel.send("That was your second warning. You have been kicked until further notice.")
            await message.author.ban()
        else:
            print("Innapropriate language detected, by {}, message: {}, warned.".format(message.author,message.content))
            await channel.send("WARNNG: please do not swear it is against our rules. If you do this again you will be kicked until further notice. If you believe this is an error please dm me at wolverhulk13#1112")
```

Namely, change this line:

`print("Innapropriate language detected, given two warnings, message: {}, banned {}.".format(message.content,message.author)`

to

`print("Innapropriate language detected, given two warnings, message: {}, banned {}.".format(message.content,message.author))`

You only closed the format statement, but not the print statement.

Comment: Now im getting an error for the next await command (the await channel.send):

`await channel.send("That was your second warning. You have been kicked until further notice.")`

This error:


`File "bot.py", line 37
    await channel.send("That was your second warning. You have been kicked until further notice.")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

(the arrow was on the "t" in await but since comments appearantly cant be formatted its not :/)